# How can I change the font size of all the screens in a windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms application in C#. I want to give facility to user to change the font size of all the screens.

Is there any way to do this in C# windows forms application?

Comment: You could have all of your controls which have text listen for an event which you fire when the font size is changed. When the event fires, each control updates its font size to the new value.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an event which you fire whenever you change the font size which takes the new value

```
public delegate void FontSize(int size);
public event FontSize OnFontSizeChanged;

public void WhereYouChangeFontSize()
{
  // Change font size
  OnFontSizeChanged(newFontSize)
}
```

And then hook up to it in all of your screens

```
SomeClass.OnFontSizeChanged += FontSizeChanged;

private void FontSizeChanged(int newValue)
{
  controls.FontSize = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The elegant and acceptable way to do it is using a resource file. You should investigate in that way.

Comment: How to do this using  a resource file.?

Answer (score 0):

You can create BaseForm for all your Screens. This BaseForm subscribe to ChangeFontMessage. For messaging you can use any EventAggregator library. This example use MVVM Light Messenger.

```
public class BaseForm : Form
    {
        public BaseForm()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<ChangeFontMessage>(this, message =>
            {
                SetFont(message.FontSize);
            });
        }

        private void SetFont(float fontSize)
        {
            Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, fontSize);

            //If you need to change font size of child controls
            foreach (var control in Controls.OfType<Control>())
            {
                control.Font = new Font(control.Font.FontFamily, fontSize);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ChangeFontMessage
    {
        public float FontSize { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can raise this message in any place:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new ChangeFontMessage { FontSize = 20 });
```